# HttpClient Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I have an application that allows users to log in via facebook. I am trying to save each user to my database using my WebApi. However, I am encountering this exception error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Can anyone see what I am doing incorrectly to cause this. Thanks.

**CustomerService class:**

```cs
public async Task<int> AddCustomer(Customer cust)
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust);
            var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Giftworx-App", "Posworx");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http/my api address/api/Customer/Insert", content);
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            return result;

        }
```

**Customer class:**

```cs
public class Customer
    {
            public string Token { get; set; }
            public bool Authenticated { get; set; }
            public string SecretKey { get; set; }

            public int StoreCustomerID { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public object Address { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string Region { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
            public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
            public object Phone { get; set; }

            public object DeviceToken { get; set; }
            public object Details { get; set; }
            public object Gender { get; set; }
            public bool IsError { get; set; }
            public object ErrorMessage { get; set; }
            public bool PhoneVerified { get; set; }
        }
```

FacebookRender

```cs
public class FacebookRender : PageRenderer
{
    CustomerService customerService;

    public FacebookRender()
    {
        var activity = this.Context as Activity;

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
            clientId: "my app client's id",
            scope: "",
            authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
            redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
            );

        auth.Completed += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    await AccountStore.Create().SaveAsync(eventArgs.Account, "FacebookProviderKey");

                    var accessToken = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                    var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(eventArgs.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
                    var expiryDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiresIn);

                    var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me"), null, eventArgs.Account);
                    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                    var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

                    var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    var name = obj["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

                    Customer cust = new Customer();
                    cust.Token = accessToken;
                    cust.Name = name;

                    await customerService.AddCustomer(cust);

                    App.NavigateToProfile(string.Format(name));



                }
                else
                {
                    App.NavigateToProfile("Invalid Login");
                }
            };
        activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
    }


}
```

Comment: Which line throws this exception?

Comment: await customerService.AddCustomer(cust);

Comment: try to check if the response code is 200 OK , before proceeding with deserialization . 
Also you need to put some break points here and there , to in which line does it crash . 
Regarding this code 
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result 
 I would put it in a separate line for a better debugging and use "Await" instead of wait.

Comment: Have you forgot to write `customerService = new CustomerService()` somewhere. I don't see anywhere you instantiate it.

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl If you know the line the exception is thrown, and the exception is a null reference... it's pretty clear what's going wrong no? You're not instantiating customerService... Are you 100% new to C#?

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl mixing synchronous blocking calls `.Result` and asynchronous calls can cause deadlocks `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` should be `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Comment: @Unicorn_Girl I would also hope you are initializing `customerService` before trying to invoke its members?

Comment: Thanks everyone! I did initialize CustomerService, It's not throwing an exception anymore but still doesn't do the job of saving the facebook user to my database

Comment: Thanks all, it worked after changing result to var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();